# Do I need to add a filter for an isolated DC-DC converter?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, filter, emc, emi-filtering

I have purchased three CUI Isolated DC-DC Converters, the models are VHK50W-Q24-S5, VHK150W-Q24-S12 and VFK600-D24-S24. I wonder you could help / guide me to the correct use of them.

**Questions:**

1. I saw some circuits in their datasheets **TEST CONFIGURATION** and **EMC RECOMMENDED CIRCUITS**, I understand **EMC** is a filter to avoid noise but what is **TEST CONFIGURATION** for?
2. It is mandatory to use an EMC circuit? I am using it for a robot where there are other components such as Jetson Orin nano, DC motors, cameras, sensors, router, etc and the chassis is made of aluminum.
3. CUI Inc. sells [DC EMI filters](https://www.cui.com/catalog/power-filters/dc-dc-power-filters),
   will it be correct if I use [this filter](https://www.cui.com/product/power-filters/dc-dc-power-filters/vfm-15c-series) for the first and second converters and [this filter](https://www.cui.com/product/power-filters/dc-dc-power-filters/vfm-25c-series) for the third?
4. There is anything else I need to for the DC-DC converters before start using them?

**Specifications:**

These are the currents each converter has to deal with:

1. VHK50W-Q24-S5: [Datasheet](https://www.mouser.pe/datasheet/2/670/vhk50w-1313229.pdf)

- input current: 1.09 A
- output current: 4.13 A

2. VHK150W-Q24-S12: [Datasheet](https://www.mouser.pe/datasheet/2/670/vhk150w-1313228.pdf)

- input current: 6.95 A
- output current: 4.04 A

3. VFK600-D24-S24: [Datasheet](https://www.mouser.pe/datasheet/2/670/vfk600-1578459.pdf)

- input current: 16.37 A
- output current: 14.90 A

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Motors itself doesn’t care about noise. The control electronic much more. Sometimes the noise can even cause a malfunction and sometimes not. So it’s up to you how far in filtering want to go. I would try to run without, check all considering enough room/worst case and then make a decission.

Comment: If you think about input filters it’s good to know what supplies the converters so we know how much “care” is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The test configuration is a circuit that is used to test the performance of the DC-DC converter under controlled conditions. It is not necessary to use the test configuration for normal operation of the converter also I recommend you to use EMC circuit since there are motors maybe noise can be effecting the overall performence.